# How to get field indexes in multiple input fields?

Tags: jquery, arrays, input

I have many select boxes, like this:

```
<select class="variants" name="variant[Color]" data-type="Color">
  // ... options here
</select>

<select class="variants" name="variant[Size]" data-type="Size">
  // ... options here
</select>

<select class="variants" name="variant[Brand]" data-type="Brand">
  // ... options here
</select>
```

Then I am sending this via Ajax, when user clicks on the submit button:

```
$.post('some_url.php', {
    id: $(this).attr('data-id'),
    amount: $('#amount').val(),
    variants: JSON.stringify(variants)
},
function(data) {
    // some code here
});
```

Everything is working fine, I just need to set in array `variants` values of all select boxes, like this:

```
variants: { Color: "Blue", Size: "45", Brand: "Some Brand" }
```

How to do it? I tried this:

```
$('.variants').each(function(i, obj) {
    variants[$(obj).attr('data-type')] = $(obj).val();
});

console.log(variants); // here I see an array
```

But in the `$.post` there is in the console this:

```
amount      1
id          14217
variants    []
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That select boxes are dynamic, its not always Color, Size and Brand; there can be various variant names

In that case you can loop over the `.variant` elements and use a regex to extract the type of variant, and apply that as a key to an object which can be passed in the AJAX request. Try this:

```
var variants = {};
$('.variants').each(function() {
    var name = this.name.match(/variant\[(.+)\]/i)[1];
    variants[name] = $(this).val();
});

$.post('some_url.php', {
    id: $(this).data('id'),
    amount: $('#amount').val(),
    variants: variants
}, function(data) {
    // some code here
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ff2bv4nb/)

Note that you don't need to use `JSON.stringify` on the `variants` object - jQuery will do this for you internally anyway.

Comment: That select boxes are dynamic, its not always Color, Size and Brand; there can be various variant names. I updated my question.

Comment: Yes, this is working. Thanks. I thought, I can save it in the array, and then use `JSON.stringify`, but it was not working, dont know why. So I just changed `[]` to `{}` and its ok now.